# Woocommerce Shipping Method cost does not add to order total with below code? How to Fix?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The below code I found on Stack works well to stop shipping calculations at add to cart and in the cart. Shipping calculations do work in checkout as they are supposed to but when a shipping method is selected it does not add the cost to the total.

```
function filter_need_shipping($val) {
    // Check if we need to recalculate shipping
    if (!is_admin()) {
        $prevent_after_add = WC()->session->get('prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart');
        return $val && !$prevent_after_add;
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', 'filter_need_shipping');

function mark_cart_not_to_recalc() {
    // Mark the cart not to recalculate when adding items
    if (!is_admin()) {
        WC()->session->set('prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart', true);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'mark_cart_not_to_recalc');


// Unset the flag when proceeding to checkout
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_init', 'unset_prevent_recalc_flag');
function unset_prevent_recalc_flag() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        WC()->session->__unset('prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart');
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you can try it:

```
    function filter_need_shipping($val) {
    // Check if we need to recalculate shipping
    if (!is_admin()) {
    $prevent_after_add = WC()->session->get('prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart');

        return $val && !$prevent_after_add;
    }
    return $val;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', 'filter_need_shipping');

function mark_cart_not_to_recalc() {
    // Mark the cart not to recalculate when adding items
    if (!is_admin() && is_cart()) {
        WC()->session->set('prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart', true);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'mark_cart_not_to_recalc');

// Unset the flag when proceeding to checkout
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_init', 'unset_prevent_recalc_flag');
function unset_prevent_recalc_flag() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        WC()->session->__unset('prevent_recalc_on_add_to_cart');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I made a mistake as I thought this code was the issue but it is something else. I will make a new post. I appreciate your effort.